# What other meat can I use instead of pork in a Spaghetti Carbonara?

Tags: substitutions, meat, pasta, carbonara

I don't want to eat pancetta (or pork) but I want to be able to recreate a similar taste and texture.

What can I substitute for the pancetta?

Comment: A quick search for 'kosher carbonara recipe' (which would also exclude either all meat or the dairy) had a recommendation for 'bacon salt'.  Others used beef cheek (might be harder to find), or smoked fatty poultry (eg, goose or duck) and replaced the cheese with nutritional yeast or left it out.  And a few used some vegetable that's either roasted or smoked (zucchini, mushrooms, etc.) or morningstar farm's vegetarian bacon (which won't be available everywhere).

Comment: And 'halal carbonara recipe' agreed w/ djmadscribbler -- either turkey bacon or beef bacon.

Comment: Related [question](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/4601/what-vegetarian-substitute-for-prosciutto-could-i-use-in-carbonara). (not dupe because it's asking for vegetarian options)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bacon is often substituted for pancetta. While bacon is also traditionally made from pork, there are companies that produce bacon from turkey, beef, lamb, venison, elk, buffalo and even seitan. If you could find one of these bacons in your area, then you could substitute one of them for the pancetta.